# Powershell Pipeline Operator vs Parenthesis

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I know that you can use parentheses to get the output of a command and use that as the input for something else.  For example:

```
set-content -path "test.txt" -value (dir)
```

will set the content of "test.txt" to the output of the `dir` command.

I also know that pipelines can do something similar.  The following code will do the same thing as before

```
dir | set-content -path "test.txt"
```

What's the difference between using parentheses and pipelines?  Is there an advantage to using pipelines over parentheses or vice versa?  I know you can specify which input you want the output of the `dir` command to be with parentheses, but can you do the same with pipelines?  If not, how do you know to which parameter the first command's output will go?

Comment: get-help about_Pipelines

Comment: A grouping expression will run the nested command, read its entire output into memory and return it to the caller. With a pipeline output of the first command is passed to the second command as it is produced. The latter is a lot more memory efficient.