# PowerShell ForEach-Object and Pipelining - upstream

Tags: powershell, directory, 7zip, foreach-object

I have a small powershell script which zips all files and folders in one folder individually:

```
dir | ForEach-Object { 7z a -tzip -mmt=32 $_.BaseName $_.Name };
```

Let's suppose I have two folders in my directory:

```
test1
test2
```

and nothing else. Currently this code will create "test1.zip" and "test2.zip", with the respective folders inside but *also contain themselves again* (i.e. test1.zip). With two folders, 7z is called four times: once for each folder to create a zip and then once for each new zip-file to update the zip by including the zip in itself. Obviously this is not the desired outcome:

```
Content of test1.zip:

test1 
test1.zip
```

It seems like the pipeline fetches an update on the new files and forwards them to the ForEach-Object command, meaning "test1.zip" gets promptly added to "test1.zip".

I'm confused on why this is happening (and even more disturbing: this was not the case in all runs), since I thought the statement is done from left to right, meaning `dir`and it's output is done and fixed and is then (potentially parallely) processed by `ForEach-Object`.

Where am I wrong?

```
dir | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ("I see:"+$_.Name);7z a -tzip $_.Name $_.Name };
```

Shows that even the newly created zip files are pipelined into ForEach-Object.

Comment: So you're saying, when the command executes it lays out: *test1.zip > test1 > ...* ? Isn't that the purpose of it? So it can be unzipped with the same folder name.

Comment: No, the content of *test1.zip* is: *test1* (the folder) and *test1.zip*, which did not exist prior to running this powershell line.

With two folders 7z is called four times: once for each folder to create a zip and then once for each new zip to update the zip by including the zip in itself.

I added that in the original post.

Comment: No, one object is processed in each pipeline element at a time.  You would have to put parentheses around (dir) to make sure it completes first.

Comment: @js2010 
Thanks a lot. I'm quite new to powershell and thanks to your comment I understood the pipeline-process now. The `dir` command is basically paused until the pipeline to finishes the first object.

This comment helped me too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354270/powershell-pipeline-operator-vs-parenthesis#comment95524147_54354270

Comment: This is a common question in terms of renaming files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So commonly to make dir finish first, put parentheses around it, or the pipeline will go back and forth one object at a time and possibly include new files.  This happens with renaming scripts.  I think in powershell 7 this is less common.

```
(dir) | ForEach-Object { 7z a -tzip -mmt=32 $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```